# How to determine what is preventing monitor from powering off

Tags: xorg, suspend, power-management

Recently, the monitors on my system would no longer enter standby/suspend/off after the configured time (screen lock/saver seem to work fine).  After it annoyed me long enough, I started to did into it.  It took way too much effort, but I finally determined the culprit was google-chrome.  For the next time this happens, is there an easy way to determine, without a lot of trial and error, what program is inhibiting the monitor from sleeping?

Ubuntu 22.04, Xfce4, xscreensaver, nVidia video, xorg, 2 monitors.